# Javascript - Push characters from string to array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, push

before you look at my issue please note I am a novice and I'm currently working through the codecademy javascript course but I'm extremely stuck on this bit which may look stupid to some. Just trying to get my head around linking things with for loops.

Trying to push all the characters from my name in the string to the array "hits".

I would really appreciate some guidance.

```js
var text = "hi it's raheel that's right raheel did i mention it's raheel it actually is raheel"

var myName = "raheel"

var hits = []

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++); {

  if (text[i] === "r") {

    for (var j = i; j < i + myName.length; j++);
    hits.push(j))
}
}
```

Comment: 1) You have an extra `)` when pushing to hits. 2) `if (text[i] === "r")` will also match the word 'right'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right... which I'm not 100% convinced I do you should be looking at something like this...

```
var text = "hi it's raheel that's right raheel did i mention it's raheel it actually is raheel";
var myName = "raheel";
var words = text.split(' ');
var hits = [];

for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    if(words[i] == myName)
        hits.push(words[i]);
}

console.log(hits);
```

However, this will push the matched `myName` multiple times so given your text, the array will consist of 4 "raheels".

```
["raheel", "raheel", "raheel", "raheel"]
```